# IIS URL Rewrite 301 Redirect for urls with parameters doesn't work

Tags: iis, parameters, query-string, url-rewrite-module

I have following rule for 301 redirects:

```
<rule name="301RedirectsRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{301Redirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

In rewrite map there are rules:

```
<add key="/di/web/home/Glossary/index.aspx" value="/resources/dental-terminology" />
<add key="/di/web/knowledge-base/article.aspx?id=62" value="/resources/oral-pathology/oral-conditions-and-diseases/periodontal-disease" />
```

First one works perfectly, but any URL with parameter (like second one) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely up to speed with the IIS rewrite module, but you could try to replace `{301Redirects:{URL}}` with `{301Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}`.

I believe the first one does not contain the query string.